# Votes from same network deleted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, serial-voting

I am teaching my girlfriend, we are exchanging knowledge. She read my previous questions and upvoted some of them. Today all the reputation from that is deleted. Why? Is this a scam as she really liked them? Also... I am a teacher and I can discuss some of the topics with my students. So now I wont stimulate them to make profiles in stackoverflow and upvoted the questions/answer they like (because as I see this is considered a scam, but its not)

Answer (score 16):

It usually takes a fair amount to get votes undone. If she's tripped off the serial voting script, its automatic, and it takes a fair bit to trigger them off.

If a moderator noticed - once again, typically because they were informed by automatic systems that point out voting anomalies, or just noticing a user suddenly got upvotes for marginal questions, and noticed patterns in the limited data we had, that would be paired with a mod message. It takes a CM to manually undo voting so, at least two people trusted in the community including an employee has looked at the voting and seen something fishy.

"Is this a scam?" No. I don't even know what you're losing other than imaginary internet points. Its a system that helps handle voting fraud since people seem to do silly things for imaginary internet points, like cheating. If it was just a voting reversal, it should be considered a lesson learnt, and a new learning moment for both you and your girlfriend to how things work here.

Comment: reputation is important as 99% of the crowd is something like: "the king is always right, the villager is always stupid". And yes these badges and stuff look respectful.

Comment: how is a new user supposed to gain 50k points? as all the good commercial questions are asked? I see nothing bad in bringing new real users to the website, that know me in real life and know my topics. Its not a scam if they upvote here, if they already upvoted me in real life

Comment: But if reputation can be gamed "unfairly" its devalued. Its just like if you could print perfect 100 dollar bills at home. Eventually those bills are worth less than toilet paper, so the department of treasury would want to have a very very serious conversation about your little operation.

Comment: I got 100K on SU. 10K here. 5K on *multiple sites* I've introduced multiple people to the site. Here's the thing. It takes a *fair number* of votes, and *proportion* of votes to a single user to trigger things off. It dosen't matter if its your girlfriend, mother or dog but its something that keeps things fair for everyone.

Comment: you mean that if a teacher from Harvard come here- he wont use the reputation from the real life? these things will always be connected. So now I have to hide my profile from the students.. thats weird

Comment: @gen.Strash The fictional Harvard professor can earn the reputation like everyone else that doesn't have access to Harvard students did, they contributed content, that earned upvotes from people they don't know

Comment: If he teaches at Harvard, I'm doubtful his SE reputation would be his only sign of his skills. [Also, superstars have very different profiles of upvotes](https://superuser.com/questions/419070/transatlantic-ping-faster-than-sending-a-pixel-to-the-screen/419167#419167) . You wouldn't get serial upvotes from one user if you were someone famous.

Comment: To set the record straight on what happened here: a new account was created, answered a question by gen.Strash, and had that answer immediately accepted and upvoted by gen.Strash. This new account then voted entirely for them, in a series of over 19 upvotes within less than 10 minutes. A moderator was informed of this, and SE staff invalidated these votes. I agree with this assessment, because this looks like a clear case of coordinated voting that goes far beyond two people who know each other.

Comment: Ow. Yeah, that's pretty blatant, and obvious. I just went by my own experiences as a moderator ;p

Comment: @gen.Strash You still broke the rules.  A use account was created, and you used your ability to cast upvotes, to give another user enough reputation, to do the same which resulted in them (at your direction) to upvote 19 of your contributions.